# My PHP script for sending emails wont send

Tags: php, email

Well I'm working on a school project, and I uploaded my script to send emails. I'm pretty much using whats defined here: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php .

Now, all I really changed(other than the contents), is the receiver, to my email address. However, I'm not getting it in my inbox. Is there something else I need? Do I need to do something with the settings on the server(or have my school enable something)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're getting a 'Mail Sent' message, then the message has been sent. Receiving it, however is a different matter. Check to make sure that it hasn't been caught by the spam filters.

If you're getting a 'Mail Failed' message, then you'll want to check whether there's a mail server enabled on your server, as well as what the error message is. You can check the error message by removing the `@` symbol in front of the `mail` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am getting the 'Mail Sent' message, however, there is nothing in my inbox, spam box, or anything at all.

Comment: @James Try removing the `@` symbol just for now, and see if you get any error messages.

Comment: @James I'm going to guess the problem lies somewhere with your mail server, since PHP only writes it to the mail buffer and if the server's acting up, that could be the cause of it.

Comment: okay, i think there must be an issue on my schools server, i uploaded a file to my personal one and it worked fine. i guess i should have checked that first. Thank you for your help, waiwai!!

Comment: What is your email address? Some providers, especially web-based ones like Hotmail, white-list email servers. I can't send emails to Hotmail/Live accounts from my home server, for example. The mail server gets a rejection message after a few minutes, but my email account gets nothing.